# Don't have OnStart() in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am beginner in Android and was reading official `Android` tutorial on `Activity` life cycle which state that `OnResume()` can only be called after `OnStart()`.
Is that true?

If yes, then there is a `class` (MainActivity) extends by `Android.Activity` which doesn't have `OnStart()` and `OnStop()`methods. I am listing down all methods in this class file:

```
OnCreate()
OnResume()
onPause()

launchNewActivity(){
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
finish();
}
```

I have following doubt here:

- If there is no `onStart()` method then how can activity will get start?
- I can find `onStart()` and `onStop()` method in `SecondActivity`. Is that why I don't have these method in `MainActivity`?

It look like a stupid question but I am confused here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have confusion with the **Activity Life Cycle**.

### `OnResume() can only be called after OnStart() ?`

One point is that you don't invoke (call) these methods. The are automatically called when an activity is created. And also there are some methods called automatically when the activity is paused.

What you can do is that, override such methods to do some action when these methods gets executed automatically. Like knowing the sequence of the execution of these methods, you can do an action at any stage.

And to answer your question, **YES** `onResume()` is called after the `onStart()` method by default. That is the sequence.

### `There is a class (MainActivity) extends by Android.Activity which doesn't have OnStart() and OnStop()methods?`

Some of these methods are not automatically implemented. And you can implement **all** the life cycle methods in any activity. For example if you wont to perform any action when the `onStop()` method is called you can simply override that method in the activity you wont it, like the example below.

```
//Overriding the onStop() method to do actions of your interest
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("TAG", "On Stop");
    //Do the action you would like to perform
}
```

### `If there is no onStart() method then how can activity will get start?`

If there is no method, still that method is being called. In a case you need to perform specific actions there, then you override the method in you activity class and specify the actions to be performed when that method is being automatically called when the activity gets created.

### `I can find onStart() and onStop() method in SecondActivity. Is that why I don't have these method in MainActivity?`

You can have all the life cycle methods in any of you activity, including MainActivity. Use them when you want to override the methods. If you don't have any special action to be performed in that sequence, just leave them and you activity works fine as the default will be automatically invoked.

The below image shows the sequence of how the life cycle methods are being called.
[image]

.

I would like to recommend you to watch these short videos which excellently explains how the **Activity Life Cycle** works.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs-lGmaMIDk&index=24&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5XP1bYBRdI&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=25

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Perfect!
So, Extended class called them automatically.

Comment: Yes. They are methods of Activity class which is extended. If you have specific actions, you can inherit them and override them. :)

Answer (score 2):

> OnResume() can only be called after OnStart(). Is that true?

`onStart()` will have been called by the time `onResume()` is called.

> If there is no onStart() method then how can activity will get start?

You are inheriting `onStart()` from `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, onResume() can only be called after onStart().

When you extends MainActivity from Activity, it means that you will get all the Activity methods in MainActivity. That's inheritance. [Check it out here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

If you want to change any of those methods, then you have to override it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Resume...");
}
```